# Find specific value in file using lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

i have file with below format :-

```
  ** Resuming transfer from byte position 13247324
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
  0 9539k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
  0 9539k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
  0 9539k    0  8192    0     0    598      0  4:32:14  0:00:13  4:32:01  1882
  0 9539k    0 13238    0     0    865      0  3:08:12  0:00:15  3:07:57  2459
 39k   11 1109k    0     0  12684      0  0:12:50  0:01:29  0:11:21 22753
 11 9539k   11 1117k    0     0  12570      0  0:12:57  0:01:31  0:11:26 15004
 11 9539k   11 1117k    0     0  12433      0  0:13:05  0:01:32  0:11:33 11847
 11 9539k   11 1117k    0     0  12299      0  0:13:14  0:01:33  0:11:41  9191
 11 9539k   11 1117k    0     0  12168      0  0:13:22  0:01:34  0:11:48  6011
 11 9539k   11 1124k    0     0  12122      0  0:13:25  0:01:35  0:11:50  2844
 12 9539k   12 1173k    0     0  12566      0  0:12:57  0:01:35  0:11:22 12479
 12 9539k   12 1173k    0     0  12384      0  0:13:08  0:01:37  0:11:31 11475
 12 9539k   12 1173k    0     0  12257      0  0:13:16  0:01:38  0:11:38 11473
 12 9539k   12 1197k    0     0  12371      0  0:13:09  0:01:39  0:11:30 16129
```

I want to find only the average dload values
My current code is :-

```
 local file = io.open(path, "rb") 
if not file then return nil end
local lines = {}
local words = {}
for line in io.lines(path) do    
    for word in line:gmatch("%w+") do
        table.insert(words, word) 
    end    
    table.insert(lines, words)
end
file:close()
return words;
```

But this code is giving me indexes , and all words as values. I am not able to find specific value for average dload

I am new to lua , any help is much appreciated

Comment: You are opening your file in binary mode.

Comment: @Zakk So? Why would that matter in lua?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. This is how I would do that. `col` will hold the number of the column for which we are gathering the output, such that you can separately get the stats for the different columns.

```
local file = io.open(path, "rb") 
if not file then return nil end
local lines = {}
local stats = {}
local col
for line in io.lines(path) do
  col = 0
  for word in line:gmatch("%w+") do
    if word then
      col = col + 1
      stats[col] = stats[col] or { }
      stats[col][word] = (stats[col][word] or 0) + 1
    end
  end
  table.insert(lines, words)
end
file:close()
```

When I do now the following:

```
for col, val in ipairs(stats) do
  for word, count in pairs(val) do
    print("Col=", col, "word=", word, "count=",count)
  end
end
```

I get the following output:

```
Col=    1   word=   39k count=  1
Col=    1   word=   0   count=  13
Col=    1   word=   11  count=  5
Col=    1   word=   12  count=  4
Col=    2   word=   0   count=  9
Col=    2   word=   9539k   count=  13
Col=    2   word=   11  count=  1
Col=    3   word=   12  count=  4
```

...etc.